# How i can improve this code (fixed navbar)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this for i can fix navbar on site when i scroll page

How i can improve this code, can reduce it somehow?

```
<nav class="main_menu">
// some code...
</nav>

var menu_offset_top_default = $('.main_menu').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var menu_offset_top = $('.main_menu').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= menu_offset_top) {
        $('.main_menu').addClass('fixed-top');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < menu_offset_top_default || $(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
        $('.main_menu').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML file as usual? Then it would be easy.

Comment: `position: sticky`?

Comment: @BenM class fixed-top have position fixed or sticky

Comment: @bp_gusar Read about `position: sticky`. Just assign it a `top` position of the element's height: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css `position: sticky` instead and get remove the jquery code

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
>   containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to
>   value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
>   scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting
>   the opposite edge of its containing block. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

An example:

https://codepen.io/simevidas/pen/JbdJRZ

Comment: Please note the browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it as follows with simple if-else block.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.main_menu').offset().top) {
        $('.main_menu').addClass('fixed-top');
    }
    else {
        $('.main_menu').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
});
```

Comment: Even shorter, remove the if-else, therefor use: `$('.main_menu').toggleClass('fixed-top', $(window).scrollTop() >= $('.main_menu').offset().top);`